# Monad "bind" function question

Tags: haskell, monads

If I define the "bind" function like this:

```
(>>=) :: M a -> (a -> M' b) -> M' b
```

Will this definition help me if I want the result to be of a new Monad type, or I should use same Monad but with b in the same Monad box as before?

Comment: If it's like this then `M` and `M'` aren't (just) monads.

Comment: … and why do you want to convert one monad to another? I don't think it is safe to convert an IO to a Maybe, for example. It's possible to compose monads (`IO (Maybe a)`), though.

Comment: Convert to different Monad so I can do more different computation, intuitively. but maybe this not that useful, right? I am looking for examples to show that there is a reason to do this sort of thing.

Comment: related: "natural transformation".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment, I don't think such operation can be safely defined for general monads (e.g. `M = IO`, `M' = Maybe`).

However, if the M is safely convertible to M', then this bind can be defined as:

```
convert :: M1 a -> M2 a
...

(>>=*) :: M1 a -> (a -> M2 b) -> M2 b
x >>=* f = convert x >>= f
```

And conversely,

```
convert x = x >>=* return
```

Some of such safe conversion methods are `maybeToList` (Maybe → []), `listToMaybe` ([] → Maybe), `stToIO` (ST RealWorld → IO), ... note that there isn't a generic `convert` method for any monads.

Answer (score 1):

Not only will that definition not help, but it will seriously confuse future readers of your code, since it will break all expectations of use for it.

For instance, are both M and M' supposed to be Monads? If so, then how are they defined? Remember: the definition of `>>=` is part of the definition of Monad, and is used everywhere to define other Monad-using functions - every function besides `return` and `fail` themselves.

Also, do you get to choose which M and M' you use, or does the computer? If so, then how do you choose? Does it work for any two Monad instances, or is there some subset of Monad that you want - or does the choice of M determine the choice of M'?

It's possible to make a function like what you've written, but it surely is a **lot** more complicated than `>>=`, and it would be misleading, cruel, and potentially disastrous to try to cram your function into `>>=`'s clothes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a complicated thing to do, but it is doable in some contexts.  Basically, if they are monads you can see inside (such as `Maybe` or a monad you've written) then you can define such an operation.

One thing which is sometimes quite handy (in GHC) is to replace the `Monad` class with one of your own.  If you define `return, >>=, fail` you'll still be able to use `do` notation.  Here's an example that may be like what you want:

```
class Compose s t where
  type Comp s t

class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m s a
  fail  :: String -> m a
  (>>=) :: (Compose s t) => m s a -> (a -> m t b) -> m (Comp s t) b
  (>>)  :: (Compose s t) => m s a -> m t b -> m (Comp s t) b
  m >> m' = m >>= \_ -> m'
```

You can then control which types can be sequenced using the bind operator based on which instances of `Compose` you define.  Naturally you'll often want `Comp s s = s`, but you can also use this to define all sorts of crazy things.

For instance, perhaps you have some operations in your monad which absolutely cannot be followed by any other operations.  Want to enforce that statically?  Define an empty datatype `data Terminal` and provide no instances of `Compose Terminal t`.

This approach is not good for transposing from (say) `Maybe` to `IO`, but it can be used to carry along some type-level data about what you're doing.

If you really do want to change monads, you can modify the class definitions above into something like

```
class Compose m n where
  type Comp m n
  (>>=*) :: m a -> (a -> n b) -> (Compose m n) b

class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  fail :: String -> m a
  (>>=) :: Compose m n => m a -> (a -> n b) -> (Compose m n) b
  m >>= f = m >>=* f
  (>>) :: Compose m n => m a -> (n b) -> (Compose m n) b
  m >> n = m >>=* \_ -> n
```

I've used the former style to useful ends, though I imagine that this latter idea may also be useful in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this sample from Oleg: http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/monads.html#param-monad